# Was any further information on Margaret's pregnancy ever given?

Tags: the-west-wing

In one episode of The West Wing, Margaret is observed to be pregnant. There's a small off-hand comment about it, with some vaguery about who the father is, but I don't believe it's ever mentioned again. Was there ever more information given about this, either within the show or by the writers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NiCole Robinson, who played [Margaret Hooper](http://westwing.wikia.com/wiki/Margaret_Hooper), said the following in an [interview with TV Guide](http://westwingnews.blogspot.be/2006/06/tv-guide-interview-with-nicole.html):

> Robinson: [...] And, let’s be honest, the fans want to know who
>   Margaret’s baby daddy is.
>
> Watercooler (Jon McDaid): All right, I’ll bite, who is Margaret’s baby daddy?
>
> Robinson: I get that a lot. A lot of people think it was Ron Silver.
>
> WC: My two choices are Bruno [Silver’s character] or [Secret Service
>   agent] Ron Butterfield, because you know that guy could keep a secret.
>
> Robinson: I hadn’t heard that one. The UPS guy and Bruno are the two
>   that I heard. I like the Ron Butterfield one.

Apparently NiCole Robinson [was pregnant at the time](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0200276/trivia?item=tr1208091), and the show choose to acknowledge this. But apparently they never came up with further story-lines WRT this.

Answer (score 3):

Josh Lyman commented that "he didn't even know she was married" and was given an 'are you an idiot?' look by CJ Craig. Her personal life was never really discussed, but she was thought to be a lesbian. In a scene in an earlier late series episode, one of the staffers was interviewing a good looking woman, and we see several male aids stop to look... the twist was so did she, in a interested sort of way.

That was it. There was nothing further mentioned about the pregnancy, she wasn't included in the episode where we saw "into the future" of some of the cast. Her sexual orientation and/or gender identity was never explicitly stated in a segment.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe I just worked it out during a re-watch of the show. In the same episode where it’s noted that Margaret is pregnant, CJ has to wear her jacket and rather unique pin after her blouse got wet. During CJ’s meeting with Cliff Callie, he says he’s getting deja vu and asks where CJ got the pin.

My conclusion, Cliff was the father of Margaret’s baby, and would have recognised the pin from somewhere. Maybe from a one-night stand?